# window.history.back() In Iframe in IE browser

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, iframe, browser-history

i use iframe inside page.
So when window.history.back() fire it back from iframe not from page..
How can i solve this problem

Comment: hi, did you find any solution to this issue? please share.

Answer (score 0):

You need to call `top.history.back()`

Comment: does it work in cross domain iframes? I was getting access denied. Is there any other way ?

Comment: @MandeepJain  That is called cross site scripting and it is not allowed.  A Iframe with one domain loaded cannot access or execute script on the parent frame if it is loaded with content from a different domain.